# Show text in a cell if another cell is not empty in Word 2010

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010

I have a table in Word 2010 like the following:

```
| 1  |  2  |
| Mr | Qaz |
| Mr | Wsx |
| Mr | Efv |
| Mr | Thn |
```

Is there a way to hide automatically the "Mr" when I clear the 2nd cell and to show it when I write something into it?

Thank you

Comment: Can you tell us what you've already tried or researched? SuperUser is a place where we try to help those who themselves have tried to resolve something, but get stuck or run into a problem. You improve your chances of getting a response if you provide details of what you've already tried. This does two things; 1) lets us know you are willing to put in an effort and not expect someone else to just do it for you, and 2) helps us to not suggest what you've already tried.

Comment: I don't know how to do it in Word, that's the reason why I asked it here.

Comment: Word is not very friendly when it comes to using formulas in tables, especially when it has to do with `IF` statements involving text. Does your project have to be in Word? If you switch to Excel you can do as you wish easily.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any formula support for Word tables. You could add an Excel spreadsheet to your Word document to accomplish this.

In the first cell add a function like:

```
=IF(B1 <> "", "Mr", "")
```

Then select that cell and swipe down all of the rows you want to apply it to and press `Ctrl`-`D` to fill the formula down.

Comment: @CharlieRB I noticed that after I first answered. I updated my answer. Not sure how it could be done with Word tables. I don't think there is any formula support.

Comment: I noticed you updated so I removed my comment. There is some support for formulas in Word tables, but it is obviously not as simple as Excel.

Comment: @Brad, you can reference cells of a table in Word which would make the technique you proposed work, however the fields will not automatically update so the "Mr" won't disappear automatically without updating all fields.